# Need to change pdf name as invoice_00000<InvoiceID> in magento 2

Tags: magento2, php, orders, invoice, backend

I need to change name of the file generated from admin for PDF generated with ID of invoice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I think we need override the invoice admin controller by using preference.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="\Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice" 
      type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice" />
</config>
```

In the custom admin controller, we need to change the name of Pdf file.

```
public function execute() 
{
  $invoiceId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('invoice_id');
  ......
  return $this->_fileFactory->create(
                    'invoice_00000' . $invoiceId . '.pdf', //<== Change the name here.
                    $pdf->render(),
                    DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
                    'application/pdf'
                );
  ...... 
}
```

**Should read more about `create` method in `vendor/magento/framework/App/Response/Http/FileFactory.php`**

Comment: How to change attached file name on Invoice email ?