# Change invoice attachement PDF name in invoice mail in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am working on Magento 2.3. I need to change the name of PDF file which is attached in invoice email.

In invoice we have send email button. When we click customer will get invoice email with invoice pdf attachment. I want to change that PDF name. Anyone know from where I can find that name and change ?

Comment: send pdf in mail its not default magento functinality. you must installed any 3rd party extension. please debug code change title code

Comment: try this link :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/59721639/11908692

Answer (score 0):

[Reference Link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/139360/72911)

In this case, I think we need override the invoice admin controller by using preference.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="\Magento\Sales\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice" 
      type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Invoice" />
</config>
```

In the custom admin controller, we need to change the name of Pdf file.

```
public function execute() 
{
  $invoiceId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('invoice_id');
  ......
  return $this->_fileFactory->create(
                    'invoice_00000' . $invoiceId . '.pdf', //<== Change the name here.
                    $pdf->render(),
                    DirectoryList::VAR_DIR,
                    'application/pdf'
                );
  ...... 
}
```

**Should read more about `create` method in `vendor/magento/framework/App/Response/Http/FileFactory.php`**

Comment: I want to chaneg the name in email attachment file. This will change the name there ?

Comment: I tried this but not working on email.